# Shed Electric help

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, shed

I just built a shed. I have extra 10 Awg wire given to me. I would like to run 3 wires of 10 gauge to my shed (all i have left) and use a 30 amp breaker. Do i need to put a 30 amp service in to downgrade to 20 amp outlets or should i just use a 20 amp breaker, run the 10 gauge wire and then wire in my lights and outlets? I also was wondering if i need to put wire in conduit where it runs thru basement? Im putting it in conduit underground but didnt want to in my basement if its not necessary. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of wire is this? What colors? What kind of conduit are you putting in underground? Do you have ground rods at the shed? What kind of work are you planning to do in the shed? Would having 2 or 3 separate circuits (e.g., one for lights, 2 for receptacles for power tools) be helpful, or are the receptacles just for very small loads like radio, phone charger, etc.?

Comment: Individual strands inside need conduit inside the house. Will wait for answers to be answered before more questions + how far distance is the shed, 4 wire may be needed unless you use metallic conduit , have you thought about a sub panel? Most here will probably suggest including me.

Comment: What size and type of conduit are you running? What type of wire is this 10AWG you were given, for that matter?

Comment: What does the writing on the insulation say? Besides 10 AWG obviously...